# getting compilation error when groovy class imported in java

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, groovy, gmavenplus

This is rewrite of my previous question as that got confusing. basically I have groovy mix java maven project. I want to invoke my groovy class in java file I have written code like this
import login.Login;

```
import groovy.lang.GroovyObject;
import groovy.net.xmlrpc.XMLRPCServerProxy;

public class TestConnectionServlet {
    public String process(String parameter) throws {
    GroovyObject groovyOject =new Login();//my groovy class
    String sessionId ="";
    try {
      XMLRPCServerProxy serverProxy =   (XMLRPCServerProxy) groovyOject.invokeMethod("getServerProxy", "https://myisteproxy");
      sessionId = (String) groovyOject.invokeMethod("getSession",new Object[]{"username","password",serverProxy});
    } catch(Exception e) {
        Logger.error(this.getClass().getName(), "error during login", e);
    }
        System.out.println("session id.."+sessionId);
        return null;
    }
}
```

when I ran it through main method it worked fine but when I compiled my maven project using goal `clean install` it is giving me error that groovy class does not exits. I checked my build path `src/main/groovy` has added. and I have groovy-all jar in my maven dependecy below is my maven dependency

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-xmlrpc</artifactId>
        <version>0.8</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.11</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.1</version>
       <configuration>
            <proc>none</proc>
            <source>1.6</source>
            <target>1.6</target>
       </configuration>
    </plugin>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
        <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>addSources</goal>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>    
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
                <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.11</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
          <sources>
            <source>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/src</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>**/*.groovy</include>
              </includes>
            </source>
          </sources>
        </configuration>
     </plugin>
   </plugins>
</build>
```

please let me know Am I missing something?

Comment: this is really compilation error, or runtime?

Comment: while I run `maven install`

Comment: Please add the actual error message.  Is the error coming from Maven Compiler or GMavenPlus?